# One time included .h functions already defined in main.obj

Tags: c++, header-files, sfml

Ok so, simply said : I've included a .h into another .h and i get a compilation error telling me that the functions are already defined in main.obj
But, well i've only included Graphics.h one time so how can it be possible that main.obj also defined the Graphics.h functions ?
I got an Error LNK2005 "Already defined in main.obj".

Graphics.h contain functions that many others files will need, but for the moment we have a problem with just one file so I'd like to fix that first.

EDIT : **SOLVED** by spliting the header, i kept the header for the functions prototypes and I created a new Graphics.cpp for the functions definition

Here are the most concerned files, I've commented the files content so it is readable.
If I'm wrong by commenting please tell me and I'll put it on pastebin or something like that

main.cpp

```
#include "main.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    sMainData data = {};
    main_Initialize(data);

    while (data.config.window.isOpen())
    {
        main_Event(data);
        main_Update(data);
        main_Draw(data);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

main.h file :

```
#ifndef MAIN_H
#define MAIN_H

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "PlayerClass.h"

// Structures...
// Prototypes...
// Functions...

#endif // !MAIN_H
```

PlayerClass.h file :

```
#ifndef PLAYERCLASS_H
#define PLAYERCLASS_H

#include "AliveClass.h" // Including the mother

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Graphics.h" // <-- So here we have our man

//Class definition

#endif // !1
```

Graphics.h file :

```
#ifndef GRAPHICS_H
#define GRAPHICS_H

#include "SFML/Graphics.hpp"

// Prototypes...
// Functions...

#endif // !GRAPHICS_H
```

Comment: Are you defineing functions in header file?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide a minimal reproducible example, but my best guess is, you have some function implemented **in the header file**, while ending up including that header, either directly or indirectly, in more than one cpp file. The result is exactly the same function with exactly the same signature, being compiled in both cpp files, which causes the linker to complain.

Solutions:

- Move the function out of the header and into its own cpp file (probably the best)
- Find a way to only include the header in one single cpp file (probably the second best in case the header isnt yours and you don't want to touch it)
- Make that function `inline` (probably the easiest, but technically the worst)

Comment: You guessed right, that's it ! :D
I had both prototype and definition in my header, I hadn't thought that it could cause problems.

Solved by creating a Graphics.cpp for the functions definition

Comment: @NicolasGranier, make sure you understand whats going on here. This isn't some kind of magic. The header files aren't anything magically special. You could simulate the way headers and their includes work by manually pasting the entire header content instead of the include line. So by including it in 2 places you've pretty much copy&pasted everything into those 2 places, including that function, so its now implemented twice. Note that the `#ifndef... SOME_KEY_H` blocks do not help in this case, because you are including it from totally separate cpp files.

Comment: Ok, thanks to your new comment I took more time to think about this error and I might have understood why the error occured. :D So... including a .h egal to copy and paste its content. And if I'm correct i did include 2 times my Graphics.h because the main.h include the player which include Graphics.h (I guess that's what you called an "indirect include"). And by so I had defined my functions two times which created the error.

Comment: Oh and if I'm right I think I learned the order of includes :D main.obj already had my functions which mean he included Graphics.h before PlayerClass.h. So when i called `#include "main.h"` the file caller had priority and copy/pasted everything for him first. And after that he included what PlayerClass needed and so on... Man, it feel so good to understand what's happening haha. That's not something school teached me haha